# InApp Purchase with a cordova app made from angular

Tags: android, angular, cordova, in-app-purchase

So I'm kinda new to angular and cordova developpment, but we have a website made with angular5, and we want a mobile app
I managed to have an apk for android using cordova.
But the thing is there are in app purchase from the web app which seems to not be allowed on googleStore/apple store, and we need to use their natives inapp plugins. Since i'm new i am kinda stuck with multiples issues, i found a cordova plugin for in app purchases but the coding is straight javascript, and from what i understand all coding parts needs to be in angular so that cordova can implement it.

I've been stuck on this issues for days now, i thought of using native android code along with it but the cordva project seems a bit different from a normal android project.

Any help or guidance will be welcomed, thx.

Comment: Have you looked at Ionic too? Cordova/Angular are part of the Ionic stack. I used it last circa Ionic 3/Angular4

Comment: Thx for your reply, i've looked at ionic, but we want is to keep the angular code for all platforms, using ionic means coding the angular part again with ionic specific plugins and syntaxes, right?

Comment: Yes. They do use their own UI components, but they are cross platform, so catering for Android iOS, Windows phone is simplified if you go this route. AFAIK  the newer versions are going to use a more Angular Router orientated approach, so it would be pretty familiar territory. And it doesn't stop you from rolling your own components if you want too.

Comment: "are going to use"  but not yet? i've seenan ionic4 beta while creating an ionic app

Again the problem i have here is we dont want to "leave" the angular code as it is still used and is under developpment, cordova seemed to be the fastest way of having a mobile app but i'm stuck with the in app purchase as im not sure of how to implement it in a cordva app built from angular.

Not sure if i'm making any sense here, feel free to ask for details.

Comment: https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase - perhaps this? I'm not sure from the way you describe it.

Comment: Hi @JGFMK thank you for your concern , the thing is we're trying to keep one code for all platforms, the website is already made with ANgular Only, since im new(again) im not sure how to convert it to ionic without changing much of the code and keepin one code, we're a team and the others are more into angular.

Comment: I too have the same problem in introducing in app purchasing in my angular app. Can someone kindly help.